# I looking very large database for Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, dataset, sample

I need to very large  sample databaset for Oracle like Microsoft's AdwentureWorks or WideWorldImporters. I searched but didn't find. Can you help me please? By the way I know to HR or other samples.

Comment: Google for "open data", you will get thousands of pages with free data sets. Example [complete transit schedule for the city of Toronto](https://open.toronto.ca/dataset/ttc-routes-and-schedules/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is some sample databases , hopefully is useful:

https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/spatial-graph-here-data-downloads.html

or this one:
https://github.com/oracle/db-sample-schemas

The schemas are:

HR: Human Resources

OE: Order Entry

PM: Product Media

IX: Information Exchange

SH: Sales History

BI: Business Intelligence

Comment: Hi my friend. I can't import World_Sample. Can you help me? I just Created user world_sample.

Comment: How can I help you? What’s the issue you are facing?

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own tables with large numbers of rows very easily using a statement like the one below. Just change the 1000 to however many rows you want in the table.

```sql
CREATE TABLE test_table
AS
        SELECT LEVEL                                                              AS id,
               DBMS_RANDOM.STRING ('p', ROUND (DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE (10, 50)))       AS val1,
               DBMS_RANDOM.STRING ('x', ROUND (DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE (100, 200)))     AS val2
          FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1000;
```

Comment: ... and likewise, such an approach is likely to be more useful to you because you can easily *personalize* the sample data.  // Also: "very large" really doesn't matter to **Oracle(!!).**  Focus on making sure that your SQL queries are *correct,* and as efficient as you now know how to make them.  If any of those queries later turn out to be a "hot spot," that can easily be dealt with individually ... later.